# Gmaps Exception: can not resolve the remote name

Tags: c#, google-maps, proxy

Im creating a small system for my university and I need to use maps. I tried to use GMap.NET.WindowsForms and everytime that run it the next error appears: 
"Exception: No se puede resolver el nombre remoto: 'mt0.google.com'

I think is because of the proxy, but I really don't know how to solve it

[image: ERROR]

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Do you get the same error when you choose a different map provider?

Comment: @Tejus Hi ! Yes, i got the same error everytime

Comment: Can you try running the application in Administrator mode? I have seen something similar with a different map control. It displayed the map tiles only when I ran it in administrator more.